# Update Data Extension field name with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I'm having issues trying to update a Data Extension Field Name using the SOAP API.

I've followed the documentation to [Update Column Properties for a Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_column_properties_for_an_existing_data_extension.htm).

I've tried different permutations of this request envelope and tried both in a parent and child business unit. I get a `Data Extension updated` message back each time, but the field is not updated.

Here are the steps that I'm taking. Feel free to paste these envelope requests in Postman and try yourself.

First, I get the `ObjectId` values of fields in the DE:

```xml
POST {{soap_instance_url}}Service.asmx
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soap_instance_url}}Service.asmx</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <Client>
                <ID>{{mid}}</ID>
            </Client>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>A7325CF7-B136-4C22-986C-18C00EE181EA</Value>
            </Filter>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Retrieves />
            <Options>
               <SaveOptions />
               <IncludeObjects>true</IncludeObjects>
            </Options>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This returns the following response:

```xml
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>a5164618-c518-421f-b762-ffd723a708f8</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ObjectID>ce0a7bc6-2ec4-4a8a-bf49-086fc4cdd533</ObjectID>
        <Name>Field 1</Name>
    </Results>
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ObjectID>7b6bb682-ddaf-4377-8837-1017e4d9c496</ObjectID>
        <Name>Field 2</Name>
    </Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

I want to update the field name for 'Field 2', so I then make this request:

```xml
POST {{soap_instance_url}}Service.asmx
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">UpdateAdd</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soap_instance_url}}Service.asmx</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <Client>
                <ID>{{mid}}</ID>
            </Client>
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">
            <CustomerKey>A7325CF7-B136-4C22-986C-18C00EE181EA</CustomerKey>
            <fields>
               <field>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                  <ObjectID>7b6bb682-ddaf-4377-8837-1017e4d9c496</ObjectID>
                  <Name>New Field Name</Name>
               </field>
            </fields>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I always get the following response back, but the field name is never updated:

```xml
<UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Results>
        <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>Data Extension updated.</StatusMessage>
        <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
        <Object xsi:type="DataExtension">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID>98ccd6c4-a1e5-e911-80f3-1402ec721f79</ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>BCAA7DAC-34D1-488F-9C06-A63E04DF2E77</CustomerKey>
        </Object>
    </Results>
    <RequestID>072195ee-09fa-4dcb-91b3-bdd066efe37a</RequestID>
    <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
</UpdateResponse>
```

I feel like I've exhausted every option! I'd love to hear from anyone who has been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, I've tried using your code without sucess.

It seems that the problem is coming from the `Fields` and `Field` attributes. You forgot the F in uppercase..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">UpdateAdd</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{url}}/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{token}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <CustomerKey>TEST_GENERIQUE</CustomerKey> 
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <ObjectID>7e97367f-4af2-4126-a703-c319780dc120</ObjectID>
                        <Name>yourField</Name> 
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't believe that I forgot the uppercase F, I just copied the [example provided](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_column_properties_for_an_existing_data_extension.htm). I think it requires an uppercase F due to the `xmlns:ns1` namespace you are using. Either way, I can't get this envelope to work either. I'm getting a [different error](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/52e9d1183ef678e4817ceb53c60ec40e) with your request. Are you sure it's working for you?

Comment: Did you change the DE CustomerKey on the code I've provided? And to answer your question, yeah, I've just tested on a new DE and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Just tested this on another account and it works. Thanks!

Comment: ha, thanks guys - I used your approach to enable field renaming in mc devtools ;-) #credit